# Include text in ForXMLPath query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlxml, for-xml-path

I want to include a line (simple text) in ForXMLPath query as

```
<Cat>
```

but I am having difficulties.

When I try it brings in weird characters with it.

Please help.

Thanks.

```
select
'<Cat>'
```

I expect this

```
<Cat>
```

but it displays below

```
&lt;Cat&gt;
```

Comment: for some reason I am not able to post correctly. When I copy paste what I am getting output it converts it to correct output.

Comment: Basically I want to  display text within a brackets <>

Comment: Hello Baber, at the very least you should [edit] your question and include the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, that your question is not clear...

XML is not just some *text with fancy extras*, but a very strictly organised text based container for data.

A simple `SELECT '<Cat>'` would never return as *<Cat>* without a `FOR XML` somewhere in your query. So please show us a (reduced!) example of your full query and the expected output, best provided as MCVE (a *stand-alone* sample with DDL, sample data, own attempt and expected output).

Just some general remarks:

- If you want to place `<Cat>` within your XML the whole output will be broken XML. This opening tag demands for a closing `</Cat>` (or - alternatively - a self-closing `<Cat />`)
- Assumably you try to add out-written tags to your XML as you'd do it in XSLT, JS, ASP.Net or any other XML/HTML producing approach.
- Assumably your solution will be a `FOR XML PATH()` approach without the need of an out-written tag within your XML.

Just to give you an idea:

```
SELECT 'test' AS [SomeElement] FOR XML PATH('SomeRowTag'),ROOT('SomeRootTag');
```

prouces this XML

```
<SomeRootTag>
  <SomeRowTag>
    <SomeElement>test</SomeElement>
  </SomeRowTag>
</SomeRootTag>
```

If you want to add a `<Cat>` element you could use an XPath like here

```
SELECT 'test' AS [Cat/SomeElement] --<-- You can add nest-levels here!
FOR XML PATH('SomeRowTag'),ROOT('SomeRootTag');
```

The result

```
<SomeRootTag>
  <SomeRowTag>
    <Cat>
      <SomeElement>test</SomeElement>
    </Cat>
  </SomeRowTag>
</SomeRootTag>
```